# TypeError when using Keras Lambda layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am learning Keras and trying to build my layers, so I build a simple Lambda layer which just calculates the mean of the inputs.

TypeError occurred in line 4 when I add this layer to a sequential model.
Here is my code:

```
mean_layer = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x))
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[10]))
model.add(mean_layer())
model.summary()

TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

However, if I use the functional model, the thing goes well and I get the expected output.

```
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=[10])
output = mean_layer(input)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
model.summary()
```

Did I build the model in the wrong way when I use the sequential API? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are doing it wrong, it should be like this:

```
model.add(mean_layer)
```

Comment: I see, thank you! But when I use layers like Dense or Input, they are used with the parentheses, why the parentheses should be removed in the case of the Lambda layer?

Comment: @TomLeung No, you are getting confused between constructor and assigning layers to a variable, you "use the parenthesis" only once for all layers.

Comment: The Lambda layer has been built at the time I assigned it to a variable, so I do not need to call it again. But the Dense layer was first called when I added it to the model, so I need the parenthesizes. Do I get it right? Thanks for your help!